# show MySQL data into web without server

Tags: php, mysql, web

I want to develop a web page to show a google maps map and put markers with the information of a MySQL database.

The objective is to make a file "map.¿php?¿.html?¿.js?" which do that. 
The file must be used in several environments, where they have local access to the database.

I´ve been searching information and I´ve seen that i need to install some web server(like XAMPP), but i can´t install in every computers or in every servers(and it isn´t safe for production environments).

Can I create a local web page that shows ÇMySQL data withouth installing anything else?(I can install a connector to MySQL if it´s needed.

Comment: Ajax ? You can use javascript without server, and with Ajax, you can communicate client->server (and your server can be distant)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a single-page application written with JavaScript that consumes a remote web service (mostly what others have suggested so far). I'm not sure though that loading the document locally (rather than using HTTP) will let you do actual useful work: you have to fight with lack of cookies, browser security and a long etcetera.

Comment: But I don´t want to have anything in the server side, only the database. Is it pssible?

Comment: Then you want a classic feature called "a program". Pick C, C++, Java, Delphi... and write one. Web technologies are based on, well, the World Wide Web.

Comment: Yes, now I´m showing it in a JavaFX app, but it goes to slow and there are some people that will have to see the map, but nothing more of the program

Answer (score 0):

You can put a single file on your own webserver wich connects with the MySQL database. After that write some JavaScript / jQuery in your HTML to do an AJAX call to the file created before.

None of your users will need an webserver, all data will be requested from your server.

Comment: But I don´t want to have anything in the server side, only the database. Is it pssible?

Comment: I really don't understand why.. Since your database is already on the server side, the client needs to connect to the server anyways. So it's either an AJAX call or running code on the client side.

Comment: I dont want to charge the serever, and i´ve Tomcat installed and I don´t know if it will make conflict

Answer (score 0):

You can do an HTML/Javascript file for display the google map without server (but you need internet connection) and php file on your server for get the data.

In your JS, you can call a distant server who contain the MySQL database and your markers.

Example, with jQuery :

```
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://your_domain.com/your_script_php.php',
        async : false,
        success : function(response){
           // Contain the response of the server :
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: But I don´t want to have anything in the server side, only the database. Is it pssible?

Comment: You need a language server side for get the data from the database. You can't use php, J2E, or other ?

Comment: Yes, now I´m showing it in a JavaFX app, but it goes to slow and there are some people that will have to see the map, but nothing more of the program. ¿could I do an http request from the webpage to the server and show the results?

Comment: I think you can't do that... But try to ask with JavaFX tag, cause it's not a php problem if you don't want use php on the server for get the data